# How to put variables in IntelliJ's run configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea

Say I have a variable named `repo_path` and I want to set some environmental variables or VM options based on this variable, such as `SOME_VAR={$repo_path}/some_sub_path` or `-DsomeProperty={$repo_path}` so that I don't have to type `repo_path` every time I use it. What is the correct way to achieve this other than typing the full address everywhere?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu linux

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define a regular system variable 'REPO_PATH' and use it in IntelliJ Run Configuration as a regular system variable :)

```
-DsomeProperty=$REPO_PATH
```

It works well under Mac OS, so I assume it will work under Ubuntu as well.